# Javascript JSON Data processed based on date

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have given below array. My problem is how to processed the data based on date.
for example: getting below response from service.

```
[[
  {"claimNumber":"6396","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/10/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"918","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"12/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2206","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2205","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
]]
```

I want to processed data based on date as follow:

20/09/2015

```
  {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2206","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2205","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"}
```

20/10/2015

```
   {"claimNumber":"6396","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/10/2015"}
```

12/09/2015

```
  {"claimNumber":"918","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"12/09/2015"}
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some arrange function for that.
the arrange() returns grouped data in object.

```css
        var data = [[
            {"claimNumber":"6396","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/10/2015"},
            {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
            {"claimNumber":"918","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"12/09/2015"},
            {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
            {"claimNumber":"2206","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
            {"claimNumber":"2205","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
            {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
        ]];

        function arrange(data) {
            var res = {};

            for(var i = 0, obj; obj = data[i]; i++) {

                if(!res[obj.dateAssessed]) {
                    res[obj.dateAssessed] = [];
                }

                res[obj.dateAssessed].push(obj);
            }

            return res;
        }

        /* it returns like:
            {
                12/09/2015: [{ ... }],
                20/09/2015: [{ ... }],
                20/10/2015: [{ ... }]
            }
        */
        arrange(data[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i would do somethink like this:

- sort data by date,
- create new empty object newData,
- iterate through data array,

  - data = data[i].date;
  - check if newData[data] exists: if not, create it with empty array in value
  - add data[i] to newData[data]

I didn't mention types convertion etc.

Comment: @Reeno Is it really a new question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter`

```
function reduceArr(x, date){
    return x[0].filter(function(elem){
        return elem.dateAssessed==date;
    });
}

console.log(reduceArr(x, "20/09/2015"));
```

This will return the array of required objects.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tpt2vgz/)

Answer (score 0):

not clear your question but if you want to group it by date, then:

```
var arr=[
  {"claimNumber":"6396","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/10/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"918","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"12/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2206","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2205","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
  {"claimNumber":"2208","itemNumber":"1","dateAssessed":"20/09/2015"},
];
var newarr = {};
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
    newarr[arr[i].dateAssessed] = newarr[arr[i].dateAssessed] || [];
    newarr[arr[i].dateAssessed].push(arr[i]);
}
```